# Ant Build giving error when using the itext jars

Tags: java, swing, ant

```
 [javac] symbol  : method setDocumentFromString(java.lang.String)
    [javac] location: class org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer
    [javac]         renderer.setDocumentFromString(html);
    [javac]                 ^
    [javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    [javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    [javac] 1 error
```

Im getting this error .im using itext jars with ant build

de.huxhorn.lilith.3rdparty.flyingsaucer.core-renderer-8RC1.jar /
itext-2.0.8.jar

This works fine with PSVM ...And no complie errors shown in the ide..
but when i runnig the ANt build this error is appearing..

Why is this happening ??

Comment: Check your jar file. CVS can corrupt a jar file when added because it doesn't pick up that it's not a text file. A lot of times, the jar will somewhat work. Also run you Ant script with the `-d` flag . This will print out the classpath before javac is called. (It will print out a lot of stuff, so either pipe it through `less` or save it as a file, and use a text editor to find where it's being compiled). These are the first steps I take when I get an error. (Also make sure you can find that class in your jars). By the way, please include your `build.xml` & any other relevant output.

Answer (score 1):

The dependent jar may not be added correctly to your build classpath and your IDE has it in the build path.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer class in the jar that is resolved by Ant build doesn't include the method 'setDocumentFromString'

Can you please take a look on your jar and ensure that the method is really there?

Comment: core-renderer 8RC1 has the method setDocumentFromString(), while 8Pre2 does not have it. Those are the two jar versions of this project available in Maven repositories.